# Bold subtitle in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, subtitle

I have tried to bold the subtitle in (root):

- My Website
- Personalize
- Adjust
- Website information

but I am a noob, and need some help; it is for my university project.

I have already looked for a solution on this site (unsuccessfully). So I need an instruction, please

Answer (score 1):

To edit the text and other style on your website. You need to do it in css. You can add your css on Appearance->Customize->Additiona CSS. Get the selector of the subtitle then add font-weight: bold; in my example its ".subtitle"

```
.subtitle{ 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi medienstadtMünchen,

in English, the menu naming is a bit different than in German, so I guess you are referring to what you enter at *Settings > General > Tagline* (coming from the backend) or *Site Identity > Taglin* (coming from the Customizer), respectively.

As far as I understood, you want the tagline to appear bold in the front end of your WordPress website.

That is very much dependent on the theme you are using. Some themes are offering settings to customize the styles.

If that is not the case, you can add custom CSS rules for your WordPress site either somewhere in the theme settings (consult the theme developer documentation for details) or – this is the approach for default themes like Twenty Nineteen etc – go to the *Customizer* and then click on *Additional CSS*. Into the CSS field enter the following:

```
.site-description { font-weight: bold; }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick answer, but I realized I have to upgrade my WP account to use CSS, so I'll have to choose another theme.